# What's wrong with my Planet API geometry filter?

Tags: planet

I send this:

{"type": "GeometryFilter", "field_name": "geometry", "config": "{"type":"Polygon","coordinates":[[[-117.187103,34.015008],[-117.187103,34.097057],[-117.084399,34.097057],[-117.084399,34.015008],[-117.187103,34.015008]]]}"}]

I get this 400 error:

{"type":"Polygon","coordinates":[[[-117.187103,34.015008],[-117.187103,34.097057],[-117.084399,34.097057],[-117.084399,34.015008],[-117.187103,34.015008]]]}' is not of type 'object'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be:

`{"type": "GeometryFilter", "field_name": "geometry", "config": {"type":"Polygon","coordinates":[[[-117.187103,34.015008],[-117.187103,34.097057],[-117.084399,34.097057],[-117.084399,34.015008],[-117.187103,34.015008]]]}}`

You've incorrectly quoted the GeoJSON portion of the filter and there is an extra `]` at the end.

Note that you also need to wrap this in the full JSON:

`{"item_types": ["PSScene4Band"], "filter": {"type": "GeometryFilter", "field_name": "geometry", "config": {"type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [[[-117.187103, 34.015008], [-117.187103, 34.097057], [-117.084399, 34.097057], [-117.084399, 34.015008], [-117.187103, 34.015008]]]}}}`

Comment: Thanks, I'm doing this in an app that generates the code so it isn't easy to validate, much appreciated.

Comment: @BruceHarold, please mark the question as answered if this solved your problem!